# SET invalid use of group function using AVG

Tags: mysql, sql, set, average

I want to declare a variable called average, what should be the average of the completiondate-creationdate of the items in the todolist.

however, if I use these lines of code, mysql tells me that I have an error in my syntax.

Can somebody tell me what I should change to store the correct value in @average?

```
SET @average = AVG(todoitem.completiondate-todoitem.creationdate) from todolist
right join todoitem on todoitem.id=todolist.id
;

SELECT name FROM todolist
right join todoitem on todoitem.id=todolist.id
WHERE (todoitem.completiondate-todoitem.creationdate > average)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `select` in the first query:

```
select @average := AVG(todoitem.completiondate - todoitem.creationdate)
from todolist right join
     todoitem
     on todoitem.id = todolist.id;
```

Although I'm leaving it in, the `join` seems unnecessary.  Why are you doing the join if you are using only one table?

```
select @average := AVG(todoitem.completiondate - todoitem.creationdate)
from todoitem;
```

Comment: the right join is there because I should only use the items that are also i the todolist. But thanks for the help! So I can declare variables also by using select @var?

Comment: @Gaargod . . . Then you should use an `inner join`.

Comment: @Gaargod: MySQL user-defined variables aren't ever "declared". Only stored program variables are declared. But, yes, a SQL SELECT statement can assign values to user-defined variables. It doesn't have to be a SELECT statement, there are a lot of other SQL statements that can perform an assignments to user-defined variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add SELECT:

```
SET @average = (SELECT AVG(todoitem.completiondate-todoitem.creationdate))
from todolist
right join todoitem on todoitem.id=todolist.id

-- or

SELECT AVG(todoitem.completiondate-todoitem.creationdate) INTO @average
from todolist
right join todoitem on todoitem.id=todolist.id
```